# How to show multiple items in list view

Tags: android

My code just show the name of the person in the list View.I want to show number as well in the List view .

> Activity

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity {
    List<String> names;
    //List<integer> time;
    List<Integer> number;
    int position;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
       // textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        getCallDetails();
    }
    private void getCallDetails() {


        names = new ArrayList<String>();
        number = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        String strOrder = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC";
  /* Query the CallLog Content Provider */
        Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null,
                null, null, strOrder);
        int name = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME);
        int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
        int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
        int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
        int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
        //sb.append("Call Log :");
        while (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {
            String namee = managedCursor.getString(name);
            String phNum = managedCursor.getString(number);
            String callTypeCode = managedCursor.getString(type);
            String strcallDate = managedCursor.getString(date);
            Date callDate = new Date(Long.valueOf(strcallDate));
            String callDuration = managedCursor.getString(duration);
            String callType = null;
            int callcode = Integer.parseInt(callTypeCode);
            names.add(namee);
           // number.add(phNum);


           switch (callcode) {
                case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                    callType = "Outgoing";
                    break;
                case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                    callType = "Incoming";
                    break;
                case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                    callType = "Missed";
                    break;
        }
          // adaptorname adaptor = new adaptorname(this, names);
            //adaptorname adaptor = new adaptorname(this, names);

          /* adaptorname adaptor = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.cell, managedCursor,
                   adaptorname adaptor= new adaptorname[]{this,names,number}, new int[]{
                 R.id.lblName, R.id.lblnum});*/


            adaptorname adaptor = new adaptorname(this, names);

            ListView list  = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
            list.setAdapter(adaptor);


}
}
}
```

This the custom adapter i am using

> Adapter

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 */
public class adaptorname extends BaseAdapter {

    List<String> name;
    //my addition
     List<String> numbers;
    Context context;

    adaptorname(Context context, List<String> name,List<String> numbers){

        this.name = name;

         this.numbers=numbers;
        this.context = context;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return name.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return name.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


//        // Get the data item for this position
        //  CellName cellNsme = new CellName();


        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag
        if (convertView == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cell, parent, false);
            viewHolder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblName);
            //my addition
               viewHolder.number=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblnum);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
        viewHolder.name.setText(name.get(position));
        //my addition
        //viewHolder.number.setText(numbers.get(position));


        // Return the completed view to render on screen
        return convertView;




    }


    public  class ViewHolder{

        TextView name;
        TextView number;
    }
}
```

This the list view Layout

> Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.moni.friendrecco.Call_Reports">



    <

ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

this is the layout for my row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:background="#5ffff7">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="lblName"
        android:id="@+id/lblName"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="lblnum"
        android:id="@+id/lblnum"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/lblName"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/lblName"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lblName" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What happens when you uncomment this line://viewHolder.number.setText(numbers.get(position));

Comment: set adapter like this:  adaptorname adaptor = new adaptorname(this, names,number ); and uncomment these:  // number.add(phNum); and   //viewHolder.number.setText(numbers.get(position));

Comment: Nops it did't worked :(

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own list of objects:

**Contact.java**:

```
public class Contact {
    private String name;
    private String number;

    public Contact(String name, String number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

**row_layout.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/number"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**ContactListAdapter.java:**

```
public class ContactListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private List<Contact> mContactList;

    public ContactListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Contact> mContactList) {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.mContactList = mContactList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mContactList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mContactList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView;

        // Get item_layout:
        rowView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);

        // Get TextView from row_layout:
        TextView textName =
                (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView textNumber =
                (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.number);

        // Get name and number from current position:
        Contact myContact = mContactList.get(position);
        textName.setText(myContact.getName());
        textNumber.setText(myContact.getNumber());

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

And finally **MainActivity.java**:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<>();

          StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
          String strOrder = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC";
  /* Query the CallLog Content Provider */
          Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null,
                null, null, strOrder);
          int name = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME);
          int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
          int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
          int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
          int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
        //sb.append("Call Log :");
          while (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {
            String namee = managedCursor.getString(name);
            String phNum = managedCursor.getString(number);
            String callTypeCode = managedCursor.getString(type);
            String strcallDate = managedCursor.getString(date);
            Date callDate = new Date(Long.valueOf(strcallDate));
            String callDuration = managedCursor.getString(duration);
            String callType = null;
            int callcode = Integer.parseInt(callTypeCode);

            switch (callcode) {
                case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                    callType = "Outgoing";
                    break;
                case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                    callType = "Incoming";
                    break;
                case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                    callType = "Missed";
                    break;
             }
             contactList.add(new Contact(namee, phNum));
         }

           // Add list to your custom adapter
           ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.liste);
           ContactListAdapter mAdapter = new ContactListAdapter(this, contactList);

          // Set Adapter
          myListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

      }
   }
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/liste"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: // Add contacts to list:
        contactList.add(new Contact("RED", "#FF0000"));
        contactList.add(new Contact("GREEN", "#00FF00"));
        contactList.add(new Contact("BLUE", "#0000FF"));
        contactList.add(new Contact("MY BEST", "#013583")); 
This part of code do not add phone contacts 
its showing me red green blue written on screen

Comment: You can use contactList.add(new Contact(namee, phNum));  I edited my answer.